# Double <br> converted to <p> in wordpress editor admin

Tags: php, wordpress, tinymce, editor, wysiwyg

in my wordpress 3.9.0 installation, I have some problems regarding the formatting of the text the admin users enter. The default behavior is that it removes `<p>` tags and `<br>` tags when switching betweeen HTML and text mode. I found some old questions that hinted to install the Tinymce advanced plugin, which I did.

So, at this point, the text enters the database exactly (I verified this in phpmyadmin) as I want it. If it has double `<br>`, it keeps the double `<br>`. Also, when the text is displayed to a visitor, the double `<br>` stays a double `<br>`.

However, when I reload the text into the editor, every double `<br>` is converted to a `<p>` tag. This is extermely annoying. I tried numerous plugins, also changed the tinymce configuration file with the `remove_linebreaks` , `convert_newlines_to_brs` and `remove_redundant_brs options` to no avail.

I am quite sure wordpress sends the database content through some filters, however I have no idea which ones they are. For the frontend, I could use

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

but this has no effect on the admin part.

Thank you,
Digits

Comment: Did you solve this? If you solved this, post the answer. So, it will help others.

Comment: No, I did not. I avoided switching between tabs to avoid the problem, but no fix soo far.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096024/wordpress-admin-editor

Answer (score -1):

Please give a try to

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' , 12);
```

I hope this will help